# jquery textbox on keypress conditional validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on asp.net mvc website and I have 4 dropdowns and 4 textboxes like this

```
dialprefix1   callfromnumber1
dialprefix2   callfromnumber2
dialprefix3   callfromnumber3
dialprefix4   callfromnumber4
```

I want that If dialprefix1 dropdown has value 44 then callfromnumber1 should

have numberic value -- done
should start with 0 0r 1,2,7,8 otherwise show alert ( not working)
if number starts with 0 then length allowed in callfromnumber1 is 10 (working)
if number starts with 1,2,7,8 then length allowed in callfromnumber1 is 9 (working)

I have coded it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#DefaultCallFrom1, #DefaultCallFrom2, #DefaultCallFrom3, #DefaultCallFrom4").keydown(function (event) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
        if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
            return;
        }
        else {
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }

    });

    if ($("#DefaultCallFrom1").val().match("5")) {
        displayAlertMessage($("#DefaultCallFrom1").val().substring(0, 1) + "Number must start with 0, 1, 2, 7 or 8");
    }

    $("#DefaultCallFrom1").keypress(function () {
        if ($("#Dialprefix1").val() == "44") {           
            if (this.value.substring(0, 1) == "0")
                return this.value.length <= 10
            else
                return this.value.length <= 9
        }
    })

    $("#DefaultCallFrom2").keypress(function () {
        if ($("#Dialprefix2").val() == "44") {
            if (this.value.substring(0, 1) == "0")
                return this.value.length <= 10
            else
                return this.value.length <= 9
        }
    })


    $("#DefaultCallFrom3").keypress(function () {
        if ($("#Dialprefix3").val() == "44") {
            if (this.value.substring(0, 1) == "0")
                return this.value.length <= 10
            else
                return this.value.length <= 9
        }
    })

    $("#DefaultCallFrom4").keypress(function () {
        if ($("#Dialprefix4").val() == "44") {
            if (this.value.substring(0, 1) == "0")
                return this.value.length <= 10
            else
                return this.value.length <= 9
        }
    })

});
```

Also, Can I make one keypress event for all four ( right now I have four keypress at the end of this snippet.

[Edit]

```
<td style="padding-left: 1px">
    <input type="text" value="1" readonly="readonly" name="srNo" id="srNo" disabled="disabled" class="tiny" style="text-    align:right">
    <select name="Dialprefix1" id="Dialprefix1">
        <option value="44">+44</option>
        <option value="001">+001</option>
        <option value="11" selected="selected">+11</option>
        <option value="12">+12</option>
        <option value="13">+13</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" value="" name="DefaultCallFrom1" id="DefaultCallFrom1" class="textarea normal" autocomplete="off">
    <br>
    <input type="text" value="2" readonly="readonly" name="srNo" id="srNo" disabled="disabled" class="tiny" style="text-    align:right">
    <select name="Dialprefix2" id="Dialprefix2">
        <option value="44">+44</option>
        <option value="001">+001</option>
        <option value="11" selected="selected">+11</option>
        <option value="12">+12</option>
        <option value="13">+13</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" value="" name="DefaultCallFrom2" id="DefaultCallFrom2" class="textarea normal" autocomplete="off">
    <br>
    <input type="text" value="3" readonly="readonly" name="srNo" id="srNo" disabled="disabled" class="tiny" style="text-    align:right">
    <select name="Dialprefix3" id="Dialprefix3">
        <option value="44">+44</option>
        <option value="001">+001</option>
        <option value="11" selected="selected">+11</option>
        <option value="12">+12</option>
        <option value="13">+13</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" value="" name="DefaultCallFrom3" id="DefaultCallFrom3" class="textarea normal" autocomplete="off">
    <br>
    <input type="text" value="4" readonly="readonly" name="srNo" id="srNo" disabled="disabled" class="tiny" style="text-    align:right">
    <select name="Dialprefix4" id="Dialprefix4">
        <option value="44">+44</option>
        <option value="001">+001</option>
        <option value="11" selected="selected">+11</option>
        <option value="12">+12</option>
        <option value="13">+13</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" value="" name="DefaultCallFrom4" id="DefaultCallFrom4" class="textarea normal" autocomplete="off">
</td>
```

Please suggest

Comment: Can you show the markup? It will help a lot.

Comment: Instead of `ID` names, why you just don't use a single `className` for all your group - elements? it will spare you 120 lines of JS :)

Comment: there are multiple classes applied to these and different ones.

Comment: whatever, think about grouping the elements you need with a single class. it will spare you 300072 lines of JS

Comment: I have added markup. can you please suggest how to make it based on class names and also how to make sure that if dropdown has 44 selected then number in related textbox starts with 0,1,2,7,8